# Зачем в слушателе сооружать вот такую конструкцию из WeakReference?

Tags: java, android

Сегодня в одном из примеров кода увидел вот такую конструкцию

```
private static final class ActionListener implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference;

    public static ActionListener newInstance(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(mainActivity);
        return new ActionListener(mainActivityWeakReference);
    }

    private ActionListener(WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference) {
        this.mainActivityWeakReference = mainActivityWeakReference;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        MainActivity mainActivity = mainActivityWeakReference.get();
        if (mainActivity != null) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO && mainActivity.shouldShowError()) {
                mainActivity.showError();
            } else {
                mainActivity.hideError();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Вот так применяется

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(ActionListener.newInstance(this));
```

Не пойму зачем использовать слабые ссылки чем это лучше старого доброго способа сразу передать слушатель

```
mBtnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {
            doOnContinue();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, что идея в следующем: в конкретном проекте возможна ситуация, при которой:

1. `MainActivity` не требуется на экране, ему не требуется показывать сообщения, и соответствующий объект можно удалить
2. Однако `mEditText` вполне нужен и хранит слушателя.

В этом случае, если бы слушатель хранил обычную ссылку на `MainActivity`, то сборщик мусора не имел бы права удалить соответствующий объект, что привело бы к "утечке" памяти: `MainActivity` не требуется, но зачем-то хранится. В случае со слабой ссылкой просто в момент удаления `MainActivity` слушатель из `mEditText` "отваливается".

Надо сказать, что некоторая утечка всё равно происходит - утекает объект класса `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь слабая ссылка на активити используется для ситуации, когда разработчик (зачем-то) решит сохранить ссылку на `ActionListener` в объекте, не привязанном к жизненному циклу (например в каком-нибудь синглетоне). Тогда, если будет обычная ссылка (не слабая), то будет утечка памяти. То есть ссылка на активити будет храниться в приложении, когда сама активити уже уничтожена.

В указанном коде используется слабая ссылка, что означает следующее: при обходе ссылок GC заметит, что на активити есть только слабая ссылка, значит объект можно удалять из памяти (объект активити удалится из памяти, даже если мы все еще храним где-то ссылку на `ActionListener`).